# Polymer swipe left or right to show new page

Tags: polymer

I am trying to learn polymer by building my own mobile app. Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to create introduction pages like the "What's New" part of the android app "Today Calender" by Jack Underwood. Is there a way to do that with Polymer's built in elements? It's basically 3 pages you can swipe through. The page follows your finger if you release your finger past a certain point it will gently snap to the next page.

Comment: if you want a polymer 1.x compliant element, check this out: https://github.com/MeTaNoV/iron-swipeable-pages

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [swipe-pages](https://github.com/TheSeamau5/swipe-pages) custom element does exactly this. Swipe to navigate between pages, the pages start moving the moment you drag them horizontally, but only change pages if you drag past a set threshold.

**Update:**

This package is for Polymer 0.5 and does not yet work on Polymer 1.0

Comment: I will have to check this out. Thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 1):

I made three CodePens while I was learning `jQuery`, so the code is a bit crude.

The [first](http://codepen.io/FlyingEmu/pen/xAwpd) one works on a loop which allows for infinite scrolling. 
The [second](http://codepen.io/FlyingEmu/pen/iCqsj) one doesn't work in a loop.
The [third](http://codepen.io/FlyingEmu/pen/CDxlK) one uses vertical slides, but you might wish to employ the bubble navigator. How they work is quite intuitive, but if you need any clarification feel free to shout out.

Here are all the CodePens:

1. [Swiping in a loop](http://codepen.io/FlyingEmu/pen/xAwpd)
2. [Swiping without a
   loop](http://codepen.io/FlyingEmu/pen/iCqsj)
3. [Side navigation](http://codepen.io/FlyingEmu/pen/CDxlK)

Comment: Nice work, if you feel like learning and playing with swiping in ReactJS I could use some help. See this Stack Overflow Question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27085523/react-swipe-api-invariant-violation-w-reactjs

Comment: @GiantElk Would love to help but I'm unfamiliar with ReactJS, I find it easier to program things from scratch. Apologies and best of luck for your problem.

Comment: you'll find ReactJS is very close to the guts, and faster than manipulating the DOM directly, as ReactJS is all pure JavaScript, and still works with jQuery if you need it. Take a look at their quick tutorial page: https://www.google.ca/search?q=reactjs&oq=reactjs&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i65l2.1517j0j1&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=0&ie=UTF-8

Comment: Yeah great work. I tried using touch to change between them. It didn't seem like touched worked.

Comment: Yeah it uses the mousedown/mouseup events which aren't called by touch events. If you need I'll tidy up and recode the examples (to work with touch) – I made these a while back and quite frankly the coding is terrible.