# react-swipe API & Invariant Violation w/ ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I'm getting an Invariant Violation error. I'm trying to get `react-swipe` working with next/prev API calls.

It's something to do with `this.setState()` in `nextPanel()`, guessing you can't call `setState` in `render()`. Not sure how to fix this ?

btw - I made changes to my local copy of `react-swipe` trying to get the swipe.js API working for slide(). See my changes here: http://jsfiddle.net/0o1737ya/

Main `react-swipe` page: https://github.com/jed/react-swipe

Another question is why does `nextPanel()` get called before I click on the `<div>` with the `onClick()` event? I added a bunch of `console.log()'s` and noticed this happening.

```
var MyPrizesCarousel = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      panelIdx: 0,
      isNext: false
    };
  },

    nextPanel: function(index) {
      newPanelIdx = this.state.panelIdx + 0;

      this.setState( {panelIdx: index} );
      this.setState( {isNext: true} );
    },

   render: function() {
      var swipeOptions = {
        continuous: false
      }

     this.carousel = (
          <Swipe continuous={false} panelIdx={this.state.panelIdx} isNext={this.state.isNext} >
            <div>
              <MyPrizesPane1 nextPanel={this.nextPanel} />
            </div>
            <div>
              <MyPrizeOne />
            </div>
            <div>
              <MyPrizeTwo />
            </div>
          </Swipe>
        );

      return (
         <div>
            <div>{this.carousel}</div>        
         </div>
      );
  } 
});


var MyPrizesPane1 = React.createClass({
  nextPanel: function(index) {
    this.props.nextPanel(index);
  },

   render: function() {
      return (
         <div>
            <div onClick={this.nextPanel(1)}>
              <img  className="menu-button" src="static/images/big-prize.gif" />
            </div>

            <div onClick={this.nextPanel(2)}>
              <img className="menu-button" src="static/images/grand-prize.jpg" />
            </div>           
         </div>
      );
  } 
});
```

NOTE: I left out a few ReactJS components from above code as they are trivial and shouldn't affect the fix.

Comment: Another weird thing, in the swipe.js file I modifed as per JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/0o1737ya/ , I was also able to access `this.swipe.next()` from render(), as well as `this.state.mySwipe.next()`. Not sure why ReactJS let that happen.

Comment: Update to above comment, this.swipe.next() is UNDEFINED when used in render() UNLESS this.state.mySwipe() is set. But what's the connection, why does this.swipe.next() start working, it should be unrelated to this.state. you'd figure ?

Answer (score 2):

When you say

```
<div onClick={this.nextPanel(1)}>
```

you're saying "take the return value of `this.nextPanel(1)` and assign it to `onClick`." That's not what you want; instead, you want to say "assign a reference to `this.nextPanel` with the first argument pre-bound to `1` to `onClick`." You'd code that up like this:

```
<div onClick={this.nextPanel.bind(null, 1)}>
```

Comment: You don't need to .bind() my onClick handlers work fine, see ReactJS pages for example of using onClick handlers: http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/interactivity-and-dynamic-uis.html My issue is how to access next() from this Swipe component: http://jsfiddle.net/0o1737ya So that I can call next() from the parent of Swipe.

Comment: Side note, looks like react-swipe is only a wrapper and it still does direct DOM manipulation via swipe.js This looks like a more appropriate way to implement swiping using pure ReactJS for everything: https://github.com/wearefractal/react-swipeable I'd still like to figure out my questions with react-swipe mods though, it's driving me silly.

Comment: @GiantElk That's not correct. The `bind` isn't to set the value of this, it's to pre-bind the first argument (`1`). As written in your question, you're calling the function immediately rather than passing it as a reference.

Comment: OK I get it now. That's knarly. I think this whole Swipe example is messy and needs a major re-write to support the full API from `swipe.js`. If you looks at the React <Swipe> component here: http://jsfiddle.net/0o1737ya I'm simply not sure how to architect this to get the API working.

Comment: I tried using `statics` to expose methods in <Swipe> but couldn't get this working, statics was undefined: http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html